# Composition vs reducing coupling?

Tags: java, oop, composition

I am getting a little confused between using objects as attributes within other objects (and invoking methods on the attribute) using composition, versus having a good overall coupling.

Is there a tradeoff here?

Perhaps its easier giving examples of bad coupling to explain the difference (if there is a difference)?

EDIT example:

```
public class MyClass(){
    MyOtherClass moc;

    public MyClass(MyOtherClass temp){
        moc = temp;
    }

    public void method(){
        moc.call()
    }
}
```

is this bad coupling because of the dependency on the composition relationship?? If not, what would be bad coupling in this example.

Comment: What is "good overall coupling"? In general, almost any kind of coupling is undesirable.

Comment: Why don't you give some examples?

Comment: Ugh. Don't call the parameter to the constructor "temp". That's a horrible name that should almost never be used for anything. Better to call it "moc" and do `this.moc = moc;` or call it "otherOne" and do `moc = otherOne;` or anything other than "temp", really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two fundamental ways to relate classes are `inheritance` and `composition`.When you establish an inheritance relationship between two classes, you get to take advantage of `dynamic binding` and `polymorphism`.

Given that the `inheritance` relationship makes it hard to change the `interface` of a superclass, it is worth looking at an alternative approach provided by `composition`. It turns out that when your goal is code reuse, `composition` provides an approach that yields easier-to-change code.

```
class Fruit {

// Return int number of pieces of peel that
// resulted from the peeling activity.
public int peel() {

    System.out.println("Peeling is appealing.");
    return 1;
}
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
}

class Example1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Apple apple = new Apple();
    int pieces = apple.peel();
}
}
```

If at some point in the future, however, you wish to change the return value of peel() to type `Peel`, you will break the code for Example1 code even though Example1 uses Apple directly and never explicitly mentions Fruit.

`Composition` provides an alternative way for Apple to reuse Fruit's implementation of `peel()`. Instead of extending Fruit, Apple can hold a reference to a `Fruit` instance and define its own `peel()` method that simply invokes `peel()` on the Fruit. Here's the code:

```
class Fruit {

// Return int number of pieces of peel that
// resulted from the peeling activity.
public int peel() {

    System.out.println("Peeling is appealing.");
    return 1;
}
 }

class Apple {

private Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

public int peel() {
    return fruit.peel();
}
}

class Example2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Apple apple = new Apple();
    int pieces = apple.peel();
}
}
```

`Inheritance` gives you higher coupling than `Composition`.

Comment: I looked at that example a few eyars ago and I understand the dangers of inheritance "propagating" errors through. So is it ok to use composition and this technique is not bad coupling?

Comment: @Porcupine it depends on your requirement if two objects are really coupled then you can not avoid it but yes Composition is preferred over Inheritance.

Comment: So normal coupling is not an "evil" its just one of those things purists hate?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of bad/good coupling, it seems like the most accepted terms are tight/loose coupling, with loosely coupled objects being preferred. In your example, tighter coupling could be something like this (with added functionality for illustration):

```
public class MyClass()
{
    MyOtherClass moc;
    public MyClass(MyOtherClass temp)
    {
        moc = temp;
    }

    public void method()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < moc.items.Count; i++)
        {
            moc.items[i].Price += 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, MyClass depends on specific implementation details of MyOtherClass (the implementation of the list of items, the cost, etc...). A more loosely coupled way to handle this type of scenario would be to move that logic into a function on MyOtherClass. That way all of the implementation details of MyOtherClass are hidden from MyClass, and can change independently of MyClass.